# How do I set up a default GNOME and KDE desktop for every new user I will create?

Tags: gnome, kde, users

I'm trying to set up an image of Ubuntu Lucid to install on some PCs at work. For that I'd like to add and remove some programs, settings, menus etc. I've heard about the /etc/skel directory.

If I configure both desktops and copy /my/ whole home-directory to /etc/skel, what will happen to the permissions?
Also, are there any files referring to absolute paths, i.e. /home/alexxhardt/.. etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this once when working on a live cd, and would suggest copying from home to skel, and then testing, and modifying individual files as needed from that point. Another thing, try using Virtual Box and a mock installation first before you do this on an actual system, just to be safe.

For GNOME you can also set defaults in Gconf Editor (gconf-editor command) by right clicking on a value and choosing to set it as default.

Comment: So there's no easy way to do this? I'll have to test and find out then. Thanks =)

Comment: There is Sabayon, for gnome only, and so buggy, you might pull all your hair out =D

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not much mistaken, certain "enterprise" Linux companies such as Novell make real money selling proprietary software which does exactly this. (And more... /etc/skel doesn't support updating existing accounts.)